# Is it a misconception that using 'EXISTS' is faster than 'IN'?

Tags: mysql

**Experiment**

First I create a table:

```
create database test;

use test;

create table user_purchase 
(
    order_id int primary key auto_increment,
    user_id int,
    amount int
);

create table users 
(
    user_id int primary key auto_increment,
    name varchar(15),
    age smallint(4)
);

alter user_purchase 
    add foreign key(user_id) references users(user_id);
```

Second insert some random data:

```
wget https://github.com/Percona-Lab/mysql_random_data_load/releases/download/v0.1.12/mysql_random_data_load_0.1.12_Linux_x86_64.tar.gz && tar -xvf mysql_random_data_load_0.1.12_Linux_x86_64.tar.gz  && chmod 744 mysql_random_data_load

./mysql_random_data_load test user_purchase 4000 --host 127.0.0.1  --password 123 --user root
./mysql_random_data_load test users 10000 --host 127.0.0.1  --password 123 --user root
```

Third I log in and execute two queries:

```
select * 
from users as u 
where exists (select 1 from user_purchase as up 
              where up.user_id = u.user_id); ===> it takes about 0.05 sec

select * 
from users 
where user_id in (select user_id from user_purchase 
                  group by user_id);  ===> it takes about 0.02 sec
```

**Question**

When using "IN" operator it stably takes 0.02sec, however, when using "EXISTS", it stably takes 0.04sec or even longer, Why using IN is faster when it has to do much more row scanning?

Explain plans:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN Select * from users where user_id IN (select user_id from user_purchase group by user_id);
+----+--------------+---------------+------------+--------+---------------+------------+---------+--------------------+-------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type  | table         | partitions | type   | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref                | rows  | filtered | Extra       |
+----+--------------+---------------+------------+--------+---------------+------------+---------+--------------------+-------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE       | users         | NULL       | ALL    | PRIMARY       | NULL       | NULL    | NULL               | 11000 |   100.00 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE       | <subquery2>   | NULL       | eq_ref | <auto_key>    | <auto_key> | 5       | test.users.user_id |     1 |   100.00 | NULL        |
|  2 | MATERIALIZED | user_purchase | NULL       | index  | user_id       | user_id    | 5       | NULL               |  5000 |   100.00 | Using index |
+----+--------------+---------------+------------+--------+---------------+------------+---------+--------------------+-------+----------+-------------+
3 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

```
mysql> EXPlain Select * FROM users as u where exists (select 1 from user_purchase as up where up.user_id = u.user_id);
+----+--------------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+----------------+-------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type        | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref            | rows  | filtered | Extra       |
+----+--------------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+----------------+-------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | u     | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL           | 11000 |   100.00 | Using where |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | up    | NULL       | ref  | user_id       | user_id | 5       | test.u.user_id |     1 |   100.00 | Using index |
+----+--------------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+----------------+-------+----------+-------------+
2 rows in set, 2 warnings (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I might question the accuracy of the benchmark.  Just for info, how large are these tables?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The `users` table has 11000 records, the `user_purchase` table has 5000 records.

Comment: 0.02 sec is not long enough to trust.

Comment: There are other uses of IN vs EXISTS vs LEFT JOIN.  That is, this question may be limited to the particular comparision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the "IN" case it executes the subquery in first place and keeps it's result in memory. That's what "Memorization" stays for in the Explain

From the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/subquery-materialization.html#:%7E:text=Materialization%20speeds%20up%20query%20execution,again%20to%20the%20temporary%20table.)

> Materialization speeds up query execution by generating a subquery result as a temporary table, normally in memory

While "EXISTS" part performs the sub-query for each set of unique values of parent query.

From the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain-output.html)

> For DEPENDENT SUBQUERY, the subquery is re-evaluated only once for each set of different values of the variables from its outer context

Technically, there are different sub-queries in IN and in EXISTS clauses

In the "IN" you have

```
select user_id from user_purchase group by user_id
```

So, it's enough to perform it once and keep the result in memory

but in the EXISTS

```
select 1 from user_purchase as up where up.user_id = u.user_id
```

The "WHERE" clause says "execute this query for every set of different values of "user_id" from parent query".

That's why it takes longer for EXISTS to perform

Comment: so I guess the common belief that using `EXISTS` is faster than using `IN` holds only when the subquery is querying on a very large table, am I correct?

Comment: @SteveWu, I'd say for a such simple query exist MIGHT be faster when result of subquery doesn't fit into the memory so data can't be materialized. In that case MYSQL will use some other searching strategy which MIGHT make EXISTS more efficient than IN

Comment: @SteveWu - Consider the case there is a `LIMIT` on the outer query limits the number of rows to touch.  Perhaps the fewer probes via `EXISTS` would make it faster than fetching all the rows of the inner table (for IN).